# ionic 2 slide transition background fade color on ios

Tags: ios, ionic2

is there a way to change the color or disable the fading of the transition when pushing or popping a page?

My navbar color is red, and the fading doesn't look good because it is white.

[before and after sliding transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3yNr.jpg)

What I would like to achieve is this effect that looks more ios native:

[transition wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI0yn.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `pageTransition`, and 'pageTransitionDelay' in the config of ionic to customise the transitions.

To do that, just go to your `app.js` and bootstrap your app the following way :

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, customProviders, {
  pageTransition: 'ios',
  pageTransitionDelay: 3000
});
```

If, instead of customising your transition this way, you just prefer to disable it, just push your views this way :

```
this.nav.push(YourPage, {}, {animate: false});
```